# How to make Spring Cloud Stream consumer in Webflux application?

Tags: apache-kafka, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Webflux based microservice that has a simple reactive repository:

```java
    public interface NotificationRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Notification, ObjectId> {
    }
```

Now I would like to extend this microservice to consume event messages from Kafka. This message/event will be then saved into the database.

For the Kafka listener, I used Spring Cloud Stream. I created some simple Consumer and it works great - I'm able to consume the message and save it into the database.

```java
    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<String, Event>> documents(NotificationRepository repository) {
        return input ->
                input.foreach((key, value) -> {
                    LOG.info("Received event, Key: {}, value: {}", key, value);
                    repository.save(initNotification(value)).subscribe();
                });
    }
```

But is this the correct way to connect Spring Cloud Stream consumer and reactive repository? It doesn't look like it is when I have to call `subscribe()` in the end.

I read the [Spring Cloud Stream documentation (for 3.0.0 release)](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/25/announcing-the-release-of-spring-cloud-stream-horsham-3-0-0-release) and they say

```
Native support for reactive programming - since v3.0.0 we no longer distribute spring-cloud-stream-reactive modules and instead relying on native reactive support provided by spring cloud function. For backward compatibility you can still bring spring-cloud-stream-reactive from previous versions.
```

and also in [this presentation video](https://youtu.be/5Mgni6AYnWg?t=400) they mention they have reactive programming support using project reactor. So I guess there is a way I just don't know it. Can you show me how to do it right?

I apologize if this all sounds too stupid but I'm very new to Spring Cloud Stream and reactive programming and haven't found many articles describing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use Flux as consumed type, something like this:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Flux<Message<Event>>> documents(NotificationRepository repository) {
    return input ->
            input
             .map(message-> /*map the necessary value like:*/ message.getPayload().getEventValue())
             .concatMap((value) -> repository.save(initNotification(value)))
             .subscribe();
}
```

If you use `Function` with empty return type (`Function<Flux<Message<Event>>, Mono<Void>>`) instead of a Consumer, then framework can automatically subscribe. With `Consumer` you have to subscribe manually, because the framework has no reference to the stream. But in `Consumer` case you subscribe not to the repository but the whole stream which is ok.

Comment: Thank you for reply, this is exactly what I need. But I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work, the message is consumed but never saved into database. Didn't you mean to use flatMap instead of doOnNext?

Comment: sry. concatMap or flatMap what you need, i modify the answer

Comment: Is there a github repo for this code ? I am trying to find right configuration to get this working with avro record instead of Event object.

Comment: you can generate classes from avro instead of using the record class.
you can find here a working example (kafka/rabbit) using avro schema
https://github.com/zlaval/spring-cloud-stream-course